# Dynamic DateTimeRangeValidator using Enterprise Library 4.1?

Tags: validation, enterprise-library

I'm trying to add a range of - 365 days and + 365 days but it appears that using this attribute in EL 4.1 only accepts a special ISO formatted string ... thus I can't simply add a normal string to this validation routine.

```
<DateTimeRangeValidator(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), DateTime.Now.AddDays(4))> _
```

I wanted to do something similar to the above - fyi

Does anyone know how you can force this attribute to accept this ISO formatted string w/out hand coding this value?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is a "RelativeDateTimeValidator" See [CodeProject article here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/VAB.aspx).

UPDATE: CP link appears dead, [here is the MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649529.aspx).